# Why do you need to subscribe to Visual Studio Dev Essentials to download a previous version of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msdn

I am following along with a book that requires me to have a previous version of Visual Studio (2010). The link from the book, https://microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional  now redirects to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ but after using the search bar to look for 2010 version I am directed to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ where the download I need is available and shown.
However on the page it says to "Select a product below and click on the download button to log in to your Visual Studio (MSDN) subscription or join the free Dev Essentials program, to gain access to the older versions."

My question is why do I need to set up an account for the 'Dev Essentials program' and am not able to simply download the software? Does the reason include needing to assign an id to the people who download an older version? Also I am looking for an answer that includes any information about the program itself, your experience with it, and any benefits of linking it to my account.

Comment: Hello iamdigiovanni, checking in to see if you found the answer helpful. If it has, it would be great if you can click the green tick box to mark the answer as resolved.

Comment: Hello @Clint, I did find the answer helpful thank you! I do not see a green tick box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1- Why do I need to set up an account for "Dev Essentials" and unable to simply download***

A- Perhaps they want to keep a record of the customers who are insistent to have the older versions despite a much newer prod release.
With this they would have insights to X customers on VS2010, Y on VS2017, this could prove useful for IDE enhancements if they figure out, probably through surveys (which require you to sign up), why some of the customers stick to the older IDEs

---

***2- My Experience***

A- I've signed up to it using my corporate account and manage our product keys and subscriptions for our enterprise account there

---

***3- Benefits***

A- You get 1 month free access to PluralSight courses, 1 month LinkedIn learning premium subscription, 1 year subscription to Code Magazine (These benefits hold true even without a corporate account)